# ASP.NET const string session key lost on PostBack

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-variables

My session key is a **const** string variable. See below.

On first Page Load, I add a string to the session using this key. I also indicate to KeepAlive on the key on the first load and every PostBack. However, on PostBack, I notice that the key is no longer in the session.

I found that to **fix** this, I simply have to remove "const" from the variable, and everything works fine.

Can someone explain and provide any educational resources on why this is happening.

```
private const string ENTITY_KEY = "c335a928-72ac-4403-b5f8-418f1e5ac1ec";

public string CurrentEntity
{
    get { WebClientSession.Current[ENTITY_KEY] as string); }
    set { WebClientSession.Current.AddTransient(ENTITY_KEY, value); }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string key = (string)Request["Id"] + "";
    CurrentEntity = Mapper.Lookup.FindById(key);

    WebClientSession.Current.KeepAlive(ENTITY_KEY);
}

private void _bindGrid()
{
    ...
    // CurrentEntity is null here on PostBack. Good on first load.
    ...
}
```

Comment: what is WebClientSession?

Comment: It's a decorator class for HttpContext. I think the issue may be with the fact that const variables are implicitly static, and I know that static variables have a application wide scope. So even if I referenced "Session" directly instead of "WebClientSession", I think this would still be a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure what `WebClientSession` is but the `HttpSessionState` will work with `const`. There is no reason why it should not work. Here is the proof that it will work:

```
private const string ENTITY_KEY = "c335a928-72ac-4403-b5f8-418f1e5ac1ec";

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
      if( !this.IsPostBack ) {

      Session.Add( "ENTITY_KEY", ENTITY_KEY );
   }

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
   string s = Session[ "ENTITY_KEY" ].ToString();
}
```

I simply added a button to my form. In the load method if the page is being requested I added a `const` variable's contents to the `Session`. In the click handler of the button, which is the form being posted, I access it from the `Session` and it is there.

**So why is it not working for you?**

There are 2 possible reasons:

**Reason 1**

The issue is in your `WebClientSession` class. I do not know the details of that class so cannot say what the issue is.

**Reason 2**

`Session` is stored in memory on the server. So, if this site is deployed on a farm, it is possible that the server which served the page initially added the `ENTITY_KEY` to `Session`. But when the page is posted back on the button click, another server serves the request. This server may not have the `ENTITY_KEY` in its memory since it is possible it has never served that page yet. In a web farm, you would want to use another source to store session related data such as a database or a file etc.